# vb.net late bindings issue even after setting the variable

Tags: excel, vb.net, binding, office-interop, late-binding

Hey all I have the following code thats throwing **Late bindings**.
[image]

I thought putting:

```
Dim excelWS As Worksheet

excelWS = New Worksheet
```

Before using the variable corrected the late binding issue?

**UPDATE 1**

Would it be something like this?

```
Dim excelRange As Range
Dim excelApp As Application
Dim excelWB As Workbook
Dim excelWS As Worksheets

excelWB = New Workbook

If madeSheet = False Then
   excelApp = New Application
   excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
   excelApp.Visible = True
End If

excelWS = New Worksheet
```

**UPDATE 2**

On this line now:

```
excelWS = excelWB.Worksheets.Add(After:=excelWB.Worksheets(sheetLoops))
```

I am getting the error of:

> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheets'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208B1-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: its vb.net . why are you not referencing Imports'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and using 'CreateObject' ?

Comment: @jonathana mind giving a code example?

Comment: no problem,  is it possible to add your code as a text and not as an image?

Comment: @jonathana check my updated OP please.

Comment: Whomever down-voted please explain why.

Comment: please  notice my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that you have to referance `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly: 
project>>add reference>> check Microsoft Excel x.xx Object Libary

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class Form1
    Private exapp As Excel.Application
    Private xlwb As Excel.Workbook
    Private xlws As Excel.Worksheet
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        exapp = New Excel.Application

        xlwb = exapp.Workbooks.Add()
        xlws = xlwb.Worksheets.Add()
        xlws.Name = "MY WS"


        xlws.Move(After:=xlwb.Sheets(xlwb.Sheets.Count))
        ' note: .value is a Range property
        xlws.Cells(1, 2) = "standard"


        xlwb.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        exapp.Visible = True
        xlwb.Worksheets("sheet1").Delete()
        xlwb.SaveAs("C:\Users\john\Desktop\test.xlsx")
        xlwb.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

**as for your update:**

even that Excel.Worksheet and Excel.Workbook are not static objects, in your case you dont need the make an instant of the (using `new`) because you are initializing them with new workbook and new worksheet.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim excelRange As Excel.Range
        Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
        Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim excelWS As Excel.Worksheets

        ' excelWB = New Workbook - you dont need an instant

        ' If madeSheet = False Then
        excelApp = New Excel.Application

        excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
            excelApp.Visible = True
        '  End If

        ' excelWS = New Worksheet - you dont need an instant
    End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to put **Excel.** with all of those? Can you not use just **Application or Workbooks or Worksheets**?

Comment: yes you can but change Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop to Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Check out my OP for the 2nd update to see what I get now when changing everything as you suggested.

Comment: i think you are tying to move worksheet that has index of 0 (the most left /last worksheet) and it is not possible to move it to index -1. am i right?

Comment: It's in a loop and will be creating a few tabs. I set all the excel calls to nothing and i thought having that would make a new one for it?

Comment: no,  to add new worksheet use      xlws = xlwb.Worksheets.Add()
        xlws.Name = "MY WS" . have a look in the code i have added.

Comment: It's now telling me that **excelWS.Name** is **'excelWS' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.**

Comment: I got it finally. Thanks for the help, Jonathan.